# System.InvalidOperationException: 'The type System.Collections.Generic.List`1 may not be used in this context.'

Tags: c#, asmx, webmethod, keyvaluepair, xmlinclude

I have an asmx which returns data to a client.
In the asmx I have the following method :

```
    [WebMethod]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(CustomField))]
    public List<CustomField> GetData(InitializeRequest request)
    {
        return xmlAccessLogic.GetData(request.Map()).Map();
    }
```

The CustomField is a custom-type I am creating. At this moment it looks as follows:

```
public class CustomField: Object
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }

    public CustomField()
    {
    }

    public CustomField(string key, object value)
    {
        Key = key;
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

When I get my data, I return it as a List> which is then mapped to a list of my CustomField-object.

When I do the following I get an error :

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, Object>> clientcollection = new List<KeyValuePair<string, Object>>();
List<KeyValuePair<string, Object>> companiesCollection = new List<KeyValuePair<string, Object>>();

companiesCollection.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, Object>("Count", 1));
companiesCollection.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, Object>("HitsLeft", _hbXmlAccessRepository.GetNumberOfHitsLeft(request.UserName, request.PassWord)));

clientcollection.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, Object>("Vat", generalDataResult.VatNumber));

companiesCollection.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, Object>("firm", clientcollection));

return companiesCollection;
```

When I don't add the clientCollection to the companiesCollection everything works fine and my clientapplication receives the data.
When I do add the clientCollection, I get an exception.
The exception I get is the following :

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The type System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Object, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] may not be used in this context.'

What have I forgotten?
I have been looking around and reading, but I didn't find the solution just yet.

(I know my CustomField-object looks like a KeyValuePair, but we have just started and there will be additional fields added to it)

What the client programmer expects, might look as follows:

```
CompaniesCollection[
    Count="1"
    HitsLeft="248"
    firm[
        Vat=423584152
        Name= "Some Name"
        JurFormID=14
    ]
    firm[
        Vat=42358468
        Name= "Some Other Name"
        JurFormID=14
    ]
]
```

Comment: A good Google query is "webmethod the type may not be used in this context".  It has too many hits on SO to pick the best dup, but the short of it is that you can't use Object.

Comment: @HansPassant And how would I have to change my code so I can include my clientCollection into  my companiesCollection?

Comment: You can't use Object, that does mean that what you posted is unusable and has to be thrown away.  Changing it won't help.  Step in the shoes of the client programmer, he needs a concrete object type to work with so he knows what to expect.  Declare that type in your code.

Comment: @HansPassant what the clientprogrammer expexts is an array of values of which some values themselves might be an array containing more values.